# How often does LEGO make colour substitutions?

Tags: colour, replacement-parts

I'm currently building the UCS Millennium Falcon and ran into a step where the instructions say to use two different shades of grey in the greebling, but the bags for that step only contain one single shade (but the right quantity).

This seems odd for such a prestige level release, so my question is whether this is "normal" or whether I should be asking for replacement parts.

To clarify - step 12, the round vents at the top back of the Falcon should contain black 1x2 grills, and dark gray 1x2 grills are used elsewhere on the paneling for detail.  The bags for this step contained no black grills - just the dark gray. Proper quantity, just wrong colour.

This isn't a case of the constructor misusing one part accidentally in place of another - the step is built with no missing parts, only a few random spares, it just has the wrong colour grills in the vents.

Comment: Which step are your referring to?

Comment: Like asked above, which step are you referring to? Those who have built the set already should be able to help you identify where the problem is.

Comment: @chicks apologies for late response - step 12, where the round vents in the rear of the Falcon should contain black grills, and the greebling elsewhere on the panels uses dark gray grills, but *all* the grills included in the steps bags are of the dark gray colour.  I have checked this against online reviews and builds, and it should definitely be black grills.  This isn't a case of "oops, used the wrong part elsewhere", hence why the existing answers are completely off the mark.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, this typically means you used the other colored part by accident somewhere else in the model, for example in a place where it is used on its own, and it was difficult to determine the exact color of the piece at that time. This happens a lot with colors like dark bluish gray, light bluish gray and pearl gray. You will need to go back through the manual to find previous places where this piece was used and confirm you used the right color.

Comment: Totally agree. I have built hundreds of sets and I can say that I have never found an error in the instructions or part counts even once. Not to say they don't exist, but the chance of builder error is just so much greater!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm talking about a large quantity - 30 to 60 pieces in a single step, not a single piece here or there.

Answer (score 3):

It might help to compare what you have with photos online of the same portion of the model.

In my experience, I sometimes find the right part in a later bag, or left over from a previous bag.

While I was building my USC Falcon, I just maintained a pot of "extras" and dipped into them whenever I couldn't find a particular part.

There's an awful lot of small parts in this model, and it's easy to skip or add too much greebling.

Comment: All the parts are in the right place, just the wrong colour.